# Qual a forma correta "Fui eu quem fiz", "Foi eu que fiz", "Foi eu quem fez", "Fui eu que fiz"?

Tags: concordância-verbal

Qual o jeito certo de dizer "Fui eu quem fiz", "Foi eu que fiz", "Foi eu quem fez", "Fui eu que fiz"?

Answer (score 13):

Tanto *Fui eu que fiz.* e *Fui eu quem fez.* estão corretas, embora, em Portugal, pelo menos, seja mais comum ouvir a primeira.

As outras duas estão erradas, já que o verbo está na 3ª pessoa e fica implícito pelo resto da frase que o sujeito é o orador, logo o verbo deveria estar na 1ª pessoa, para que concordem em género.

Comment: Não me parece que "Fui eu quem fiz" esteja correto.

Comment: Quem foi que comprou aquele sumo? Quem comprou aquele sumo fui eu. Quem foi que fez aquele sumo? Quem fez aquele sumo fui eu.

Comment: Acho que é "fui eu quem fez"

Comment: http://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/fui-eu-que-fiz-ou-fui-eu-quem-fez.html

Comment: Ah, ok. Suponho que estava errado, então.

Comment: comprou é a terceira pessoa do singular assim como fez.

Comment: O site que @Jorge indicou diz que "Fui eu quem recitou" e "fui eu quem recitei" estão ambos corretos! Portanto "Fui eu quem fiz" também está (mas soa-me estranho). Logo, someonewithpc, não estavas errado.

Answer (score 9):

Todas as opções começadas com *foi eu* estão erradas: o primeiro verbo tem que concordar com o sujeito, portanto, *fui eu...* Tendo o começo correto, todas as fontes que consultei dizem a mesma coisa: há três possibilidades correctas:

> Fui eu que fiz.
>   Fui eu quem fez.
>   Fui eu quem fiz.

A única que não é válida é *fui eu que fez*. O [Professor Paulo Fernandes](http://www.paulohernandes.pro.br/dicas/001/dica007.html) trata especificamente estes exemplos. [Este artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-dos-pronomes-quem-e-que/31037) discute também a concordância com *que* e *quem*. O pronome relativo *que* concorda em género e número com o antecedente, ou seja, com o nome a que o *que* se refere:

> Foram eles que fizeram.
>   Fomos nós que fizemos.
>   Foste tu que fizeste.

Com o pronome relativo *quem*, parece que os alguns gramáticos (vejam artigo do Ciberdúvidas) preferem a concordância sempre com a terceira pessoa do singular, mas a concordância com o antecedente do *quem* é também aceite:

> *Foram eles quem fez* ou *foram eles quem fizeram*.
>   *Fomos nós quem fez* ou *fomos nós quem fizemos*.
>   *Foste tu quem fez* ou *foste tu quem fizeste*.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que as combinações possíveis são `quem fez` ou `que fiz`, a não ser que se esteja usando uma figura de linguagem.

O `que` recupera o sujeito. Compare com

> Fomos nós que fizemos.

(e não `fomos nos que fez`) e também

> Fomos nós quem fez.

Se a segunda frase soa estranha, tente desfazer a inversão: `quem fez fomos nós`.

Comment: A primeira frase, não sei não...

Comment: Pensei em `Foi Maluf quem fez.`

Comment: Não era `Foi Maluf QUE fez`? Só sei que ele roubou :)

Comment: Mesmo assim, nesse caso (3a pessoa), tanto faz: "Maluf foi quem fez" / "quem fez foi Maluf" estão ambas corretas; mas na 1a pessoa seria "quem fez fui eu" / "fui eu quem fez". Acho que "fez" e "fiz" são até intercambiáveis nesses exemplos, mas não "foi" e "fui".

Comment: retirei o voto negativo, agora sim está certo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Os dois exemplos do Tássio estão ambos corretos. "Fomos nós quem fizemos" também está. [Ver aqui](http://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/fui-eu-que-fiz-ou-fui-eu-quem-fez.html) ou [aqui](http://www.paulohernandes.pro.br/dicas/001/dica007.html).

Comment: @JorgeB. Já agora, depois de retirar o voto negativo, podias dar um positivo. Isto parece muito mal, -4, e a resposta nem está pior do que a que tem +10.

Comment: @Jacinto o problema foi a primeira resposta antes da edição. Eu retirei o voto, mas ninguém se lembrou de fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Eu percebi isso. Mas isto ficou com muito mau aspeto. E como temos alguma confiança, pensei em pedir para ajudares a mudar. Eu já fiz o que pude.