# O que é "Concordância Verbal"?

Tags: gramática, concordância-verbal

O que realmente é concordância verbal na língua portuguesa?

Existe diferença no significado de concordância verbal no Português(PT) para o Português(BR)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concordância com um constituinte significa que todos os constituintes da frase devem concordar,  i.e. ter o mesmo, em número, género e grau (se aplicável). Caso isto não aconteça, a frase esta incorreta.

Um exemplo: *Os casa sou grandes.* está frase não está correta pois o determinante não concorda em género nem número com o sujeito e porque o verbo não concorda em número com o sujeito.

Answer (score 5):

Compare as seguintes frases:

> O casa estão muita sujo.
>
> A casa está muito suja.

O que falta na primeira frase? Concordância.

Como foi possível ver nesse exemplo, concordância verbal é, como o nome diz, o acordo na "forma" das palavras de uma frase, ou seja, como no exemplo da casa, se um sujeito é feminino os adjetivos que a ele se referem também devem estar na forma feminina, e assim por diante.

Agora, explicando as discordâncias da frase de exemplo, depois do "o", masculino, em desacordo com "casa", que é feminino, tem o "estão", que está em discordância com "a casa", que está na terceira pessoa do singular. Depois dele tem o "muita", que além de estar no feminino, ainda por cima não faz sentido por ser um pronome indefinido significando "em grande quantidade", ao invés de "muito" que é advérbio de intensidade significando "demasiadamente". E por último, "sujo" que também está em discordância com "casa" que é feminino.

[Aqui](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint49.php) para maiores informações (clique em "Próxima" embaixo para continuar).

Answer (score 4):

**Concordância verbal** é o mesmo no Brasil e em Portugal, e significa a conjugação do verbo de acordo com o sujeito da frase. Exemplos:

> Concordância: *eu digo*. Falta de concordância: *eu dizemos, eu diz.*
>
> Concordância: *eles falaram*. Falta de concordância: *eles falou, eles falei.*

Um erro de concordância algo frequente em Portugal é na segunda pessoa do singular do pretérito perfeito do indicativo (ufa, fiquei sem fôlego): ouve-se, por exemplo, por vezes dizer *tu falastes*. Está errado: é *tu falaste* ou *vós falastes.* Este erro é talvez facilitado por pouca gente usar o *vós*. Talvez no norte, onde ainda há quem use, seja menos frequente.

Agora, quando o sujeito da frase é uma das pessoas gramaticais, *eu, tu, ele, nós, vós, eles*, a concordância é muito simples. As coisas tornam-se mais interessantes quando temos sujeitos como *a gente, um de nós, a maioria deles, nem eu nem ela, os Estados Unidos*, etc. etc. Alguns destes casos já foram debatidos aqui na comunidade, e eu indico abaixo os links dos que conheço. Então, a concordância verbal determina:

> [Um terço das mulheres **está** grávido ou **estão** grávidas?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/um-ter%C3%A7o-das-mulheres-presentes-pode-estar-gr%C3%A1vida)
>
> [Fui eu **que fiz** ou fui eu **que fez**? Fui eu **quem fiz** ou fui eu **quem fez**?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/59/qual-a-forma-correta-fui-eu-quem-fiz-foi-eu-que-fiz-foi-eu-quem-fez-fu)
>
> [A maioria de nós **foi**, a maioria de nós **fomos**, ou a maioria de nós **foram**?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/a-maior-parte-e-concord%C3%A2ncia-verbal)

E noutros casos complicados de concordância verbal podem sempre consultar [o manual de redação da Pontifícia Universidade Católica do Rio Grande do Sul](http://www.pucrs.br/manualred/verbal.php)