# "A maior parte" e concordância verbal

Tags: concordância-verbal

Todas estas frases me parecem possíveis. Pela ordem da minha preferência:

> A maior parte de nós concorda.
>   A maior parte de nós concordamos.
>   A maior parte de nós concordam.

O mesmo para outras expressões partitivas: "metade de nós", "maioria de nós" (embora com "maioria" eu tenha maior preferência pelo singular). Não noto muita diferença entre "concorda" e "concordam", mas "concordamos" parece-me indicar que o locutor se inclui na grupo.

O mesmo para a segunda pessoa do plural (sem nenhuma ordem em particular):

> A maior parte de vós concorda.
>   A maior parte de vós concordais.
>   A maior parte de vós concordam.

Também aqui me parece que o interlocutor é necessariamente incluído na segunda frase.

E para a terceira:

> A maior parte deles concorda.
>   A maior parte deles concordam.

A pergunta é:

- Que formas são preferidas?
- Notam alguma diferença de significado entre elas?

Comment: Eu costumo optar pelo singular. Excluis "a maior parte de vós concorda"?

Comment: @Jacinto Obrigado, tinha-me escapado. Se bem que com "a maior parte de vós", não consigo dizer bem qual me parece melhor. Aí, talvez as no plural. Talvez se houver aqui alguém de Chaves...

Comment: Eu tenho ideia que o que determina tudo é o número gramatical do sujeito, que nesses casos julgo ser determinado por **parte**. Não é como os britânicos que dizem "the team are..."

Comment: @Jacinto As fontes que consultei indicam que ambas são possíveis. Vê por exemplo https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/concordancia-do-verbo/1528 , embora não me reveja nas distinções que são aí feitas.

Comment: Segundo o [Manual de Redação da PUCRS](http://www.pucrs.br/manualred/verbal.php), ambas as formas são aceitas, tanto no singular quanto no plural. Embora que seja muito mais comum, e eu ache bem melhor, sempre no singular.

Comment: @BrunoLopes e Artefacto: andamos a ler a mesmas coisas

Comment: @BrunoLopes e Artefacto. Genial: [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/concordancia-do-verbo/1528) contra [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/uso-de-maioria/15997)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pelo que eu apurei a tendência entre os gramáticos nestes casos é para aceitar a conjugação quer no singular quer no plural. E isto vale não só para os exemplos da pergunta, mas em geral para sujeitos constituídos por substantivo plural precedido de (a) expressão partitiva (maioria, uma parte, etc.) ou (b) substantivo coletivo singular:

> (b) *A maioria dos fãs **era** jovem* ou *a maioria dos fãs **eram** jovens.*
>
> (c) *A multidão dos fãs **ficou** delirante* ou *a multidão dos fãs **ficaram** delirantes.*

No entanto muitos gramáticos, possivelmente a maioria, prefere o singular. Vejam por exemplo no [Brasil Escola](http://www.brasilescola.com/gramatica/a-maioria-grande-parte-maior-parte-boa-parte-parte.htm). Mas encontrei apenas uma voz a dizer que [errado é, porém, **a maioria das pessoas** (vezes, etc.) **são** ou **estão** em vez de **é** ou **está**](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/uso-de-maioria/15997). Como em vários outros sites, o [manual de redação da Pontifícia Universidade Católica do Rio Grande do Sul](http://www.pucrs.br/manualred/verbal.php) apresenta simplesmente as duas possibilidades sem fazer qualquer recomendação.

Agora o que eu achei mais interessante foram vários artigos que abordam a concordância siléptica. Silepse é a concordância, não com o sujeito gramatical, mas com a ideia expressa por esse sujeito. Neste exemplo de Alexandre Herculano citado [aqui no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/concordancia-total-e-parcial-ou-atractiva/13955):

> A **plebe vociferava** as mais afrontosas injúrias contra D. Leonor; e se **chegassem** a entrar no paço, ela sem dúvida seria feita em pedaços pelo tropel furioso.

O sujeito gramatical é **plebe**, singular, mas a ideia é plural. O primeiro verbo, **vociferava**, obedece à concordância gramatical, mas o segundo, **chegassem**, obedece à concordância siléptica. Em todos os exemplos da resposta do Cigano Mendez a concordância siléptica dá o mesmo resultado que a concordância atrativa (concordância com o elemento do sujeito mais próximo); mas no exemplo anterior, a concordância atrativa dá o mesmo resultado que a gramatical.

Este [outro artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/concordancia-do-verbo/1528) diz que a concordância siléptica pode ser preferível em certos contextos. Não explica quais. Mas ele diz que a concordância gramatical é melhor no exemplo:

> Um grupo de trabalhadores da empresa X fez uma manifestação em frente à Assembleia da República,

porque o grupo é apresentado como coeso, “mais como uma unidade do que como uma pluralidade.” Subentende-se então que a concordância siléptica é preferível se o grupo não for tão coeso e seja mais natural entendê-lo como uma pluralidade. É por isso que no exemplo do Cigano Mendez

> Um terço das mulheres presentes está grávido/Um terço das mulheres presentes estão grávidas,

a concordância siléptica soa muito melhor: as mulheres não se juntaram numa gravidez coletiva. Além disso temos a questão do género, em que a concordância gramatical, grávido, soa estranha. Também nos seguintes exemplos me parece que a concordância siléptica soa mais natural:

> A maioria dos rapazes foi dançar com a sua namorada/a maioria dos rapazes foram dançar com as suas namoradas.
>
> A maioria das casas do município estão espalhadas pelos campos/a maioria das casas do município está espalhada pelos campos.

Este [terceiro ou quarto artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-a-silepse-na-concordancia-com-a-gente/29794), depois de muitos entretantos, tem também um discussão interessante com exemplos do uso da silepse. Resta a questão do:

> A maioria de nós **fomos**/a maioria de nós **foram**.

O [manual de redação da Pontifícia Universidade Católica do RGS](http://www.pucrs.br/manualred/verbal.php) apresenta um caso algo parecido. Diz que os casos seguintes são ambos possíveis:

> (a) Alguns de nós **lemos** o livro/(b) alguns de nós **leram** o livro

Logo conjugando esta possibilidade com o uso da conjugação plural para sujeito singular, resulta que todas as possibilidades do Artefacto são possíveis:

> A maioria de nós foi/foram/fomos.

As discussões em volta da silepse apoiam talvez a intuição do Artefacto: dizer **a maioria de nós fomos** quando o locutor faz parte dessa maioria. Na verdade, parece-me que o que a silepse faz é precisamente apelar à intuição.

Comment: Mais uma excelente resposta como sempre.

Comment: @JorgeB. Obrigado. Fiquei contente por a resposta ser esta. Gosto da concordância siléptica. Vou começar a usá-la mais, até para provocar os puristas.

Comment: Boa resposta. Já agora, pesquisei `(("a" "maior" "parte") | ("a" "maioria") | "metade" | ("um" "terço")) (([lema="de"] [pessnum=".*P"]) | ([lema="de\+.*" & pessnum=".*P"])) [pos!="PU"]{0,2} @[pos="V.*" & temcagr!="PCP"]` no CETEMPúblico (Distribuição de pessnum), e a preferência entre singular e plural não é muito marcada (menos do doubro para o singular), e isto inclui o infinitivo, que não é possível distinguir entre o singular e o impessoal.

Comment: Não estou a apanhar essa do infinitivo. Dás-me um exemplo?

Comment: @Jacinto Se vires os resultados da query, encontras frases como esta: " Miguel Sousa Tavares confronta-o com o facto de a maior parte dos impostos ser paga em Lisboa". Eu estava a pensar que estes casos podiam ser infinitivo impessoal em vez de infinitivo pessoal na 3a pessoa de singular (a forma é a mesma), mas, pensando melhor, o infinitivo impessoal não é possível nestas frases logo a seguir a um sujeito explícito: não se pode dizer *"confronta-o com o facto de todos os impostos ser pagos em Lisboa".

Answer (score 8):

Isso faz parte da concordância que chamamos de **partitativa**. Para estes casos, o verbo não necessariamente precisa concordar com o núcleo do sujeito da oração. [O verbo pode concordar com a partícula mais próxima](http://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/concordancia-com-partitivos-seguidos-de-plural.jhtm):

> A **maior parte** de nós concorda. (concordância gramatical)
>
> A maior parte de **nós** concordamos. (concordância atrativa)
>
> A maior parte de **nós** concordam. (idem)

Em alguns casos, note que, apesar de não seguir a gramática, a concordância do predicativo com o termo mais próximo é bem mais natural:

> Um **terço das mulheres** presentes está grávido. (concordância gramatical)
>
> Um terço das **mulheres** presentes estão grávidas. (concordância atrativa)

Comment: Este [artigo no ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/concordancia-do-verbo/1528) chama _concordância siléptica_ a uma coisa que nos teus exemplos dá o mesmo resultado que a concordância atrativa. Diz que a concordância gramatical é preferível quando o coletivo é coeso. Subentende-se que a concordância siléptica é preferível em casos como um terço das mulheres grávidas, que estão iindividualmente, e não coletivamente, grávidas.

Comment: Os gramáticos normativos aceitam a existência de "concordância atrativa"?

Comment: @Centaurus É uma boa pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Quando o assunto é concordância verbal, há muitas dúvidas e essas suas são bem clássicas.
Como a questão é sobre singular e plural, você se dirigir à palavra em questão.

Em sua primeira dúvida, ao citar "NÓS", você faz parte da "turma" e o verbo deve concordar com o sujeito dessa forma:

- "A maior/metade/menor parte de NÓS CONCORDAMOS."

Segunda e terceira dúvida:

Já VÓS é o plural de TU e você não faz parte desse grupo. É como "VOCÊS". Aí, a frase correta é:

- "A maior/metade/menor parte de VÓS CONCORDAM."
- "A maior/metade/menor parte de VOCÊS CONCORDAM"

Agora, imagine-se assistindo uma votação no Senado (credo!). Você não faz parte da "turma" e nem nos referimos a eles diretamente por "vocês".
Então a frase muda para

- A maioria/minoria CONCORDA.

Por que no singular? Porque "maioria/minoria" está no singular E TAMBÉM não incita o plural. Quer um exemplo no plural?

- A maioria das empresas CONCORDAM. (é o caso de VÓS/VOCÊS).

Deu pra compreender um pouco? Se sim, fico feliz.