# Concordância verbal em sequência com singular e plural: qual deve ser considerado para concordar?

Tags: concordância-verbal, concordância

Nesse tipo de frase:

> Grande parte dos indivíduos ainda **desconhece** [...]

Fico na dúvida se o verbo "desconhecer" deve concordar com "grande parte" (que está no singular) ou com "indivíduos" (que está no plural).

Acabo ficando na dúvida em qual das duas está correta:

- Grande parte dos **indivíduos** ainda **desconhecem** [...]
- **Grande parte** dos indivíduos ainda **desconhece** [...]

Comment: Uma boa pergunta e assunto para um longa resposta.  Aparentemente a resposta é simples: se o sujeito for apenas "a maior parte", "a maioria", "grande parte", o singular é óbvio.. Contudo, se o sujeito estiver no plural, como em "grande parte dos alunos", "a maioria dos moradores" e, além disso, o verbo a seguir for "ser", "estar", ou "ficar", a coisa já não é tão simples assim..

Comment: Acredito que a regra siga a mesma lógica da usada quando há [porcentagens/valores numéricos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/6333/2759)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr   Porque dizemos "acredito que ela *siga*",  mas dizemos "acho que ela *segue*?

Comment: @Centaurus, no meu caso, optei pelo modo subjuntivo, que indica incerteza, mas foi natural/inconsciente.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr   Você não entendeu a minha pergunta.  Podemos dizer "acredito que ela *segue*" e "acredito que ela *siga*".  Mas com o verbo *achar* eu sempre ouvi "acho que ela *segue*..." e, embora gramaticalmente correto, não me parece idiomático dizer "acho que ela *siga*."

Comment: @Centaurus, eu creio que a resposta a se isso está ou não certo é treta de gramáticos. Honestamente, acho que há quem dizem que sim e que não.

Comment: Simplificando âmbalas frases, “grande parte ainda desconhece” ou “dos indivíduos ainda desconhecem”. Independentemente do que vem acompanhado ao sujeito, o verbo deve concordar com o sujeito, certo? A segunda pode parecer que é sujeito indeterminado, mas ao meu ver pode também ser uma omissão de “que”, “dos indivíduos [que] ainda desconhecem”. Também pode ser equivalente a “dos indivíduos, eles/vários ainda desconhecem”, semi-equivalente a “aqueles [parte] dos indivíduos ainda desconhecem”, ou ‘seje’, “alguns indivíduos ainda desconhecem”.

Comment: @Centaurus realmente entendi errado. Confesso que "acho que ela siga" soa estranho. Numa rápida pesquisa, percebi que há poucas ocorrências de "acho que ela siga" e "talvez ela siga".

Comment: Luiz, tens [esta pergunta sobre mesmo assunto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/a-maior-parte-e-concord%C3%A2ncia-verbal/1135#1135), com duas respostas que creio que respondem à tua questão.

Comment: Oi @Jacinto, é isso mesmo, muito obrigado! :)