# Concordância Verbal - número a ser desenvolvidas

Tags: português-brasileiro, verbos, concordância-verbal

"Número mínimo de prospecções ativas a ser desenvolvidas na semana"
OU
"Número mínimo de prospecções ativas a ser desenvolvido na semana" ?

Qual a forma correta?

Comment: Bem-vindo, Wagner. Sugeri um titulo novo, que deixe mais claro numa lista de que se trata a pergunta - mas é só uma sugestão, sinta-se à vontade para reverter ou alterar, se achar apropriado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambas (quase). A segunda opção está correta como sugerida:

> Número mínimo de prospecções ativas a ser desenvolvido na semana

em que "ser" concorda com "número". E a primeira opção também está, mas com uma correção, "ser" -> "serem":

> Número mínimo de prospecções ativas a serem desenvolvidas na semana

que então concorda com "prospecções".

Com relação a possíveis diferenças de significado, se pode argumentar que esta última versão é menos preferível, pois pareceria se referir a um conceito de "prospecções a serem desenvolvidas na semana" (das quais há um número mínimo), enquanto um "número mínimo a ser desenvolvido na semana" faria mais sentido — mas também se poderia argumentar o oposto: que é mais natural se falar em "desenvolvimento de prospecções" do que em "desenvolvimento de um número". Mas essas distinções são sutis e discutíveis, e não têm mais a ver com gramática, porque nesse tipo de caso [se aceita a conjugação tanto no singular quanto no plural](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1120/2764).