# Um terço das mulheres presentes pode estar grávida?

Tags: concordância-verbal, concordância-nominal

Esta dúvida surgiu-me a partir dos [exemplos](http://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/concordancia-com-partitivos-seguidos-de-plural.jhtm)

> (a) Um terço das mulheres presentes **está grávido**.
>
> (b) Um terço das mulheres presentes **estão grávidas**.

Estes exemplos foram discutidos nas respostas à pergunta: [a maior parte concorda, concordamos ou concordam?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/a-maior-parte-e-concord%C3%A2ncia-verbal/1135#1135) Os dois exemplos anteriores são geralmente aceites pelo gramáticos: (a) é um exemplo de concordância gramatical (geralmente o preferido), (b), de concordância atrativa ou siléptica (são dois tipos de concordância diferentes, que naquele exemplo coincidem no resultado). Quando apresentei o exemplo (a) a dois colegas, eles imediatamente disseram que era:

> (c) Um terço das mulheres **está grávida**.

Ora o problema é que esta frase, não me soando mal, é uma salgalhada de concordâncias: o verbo concorda com *terço*, enquanto o adjetivo concorda com *terço* no número, mas com *mulheres* no género.

Entretanto descobri [este artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/concordancia-com-um-terco/17690) que:

> **Aceita** *um terço das portuguesas **é iletrado**.*
> **Aceita** *um terço das portuguesas **são iletradas**.*
> **Rejeita** *um terço das portuguesas **é iletrada**.*

Ou seja, rejeita uma estrutura equivalente à que propus para discussão. Mas como o Ciberdúvidas não é Deus, eu mantenho a pergunta aberta: **é aceitável, correto, até mesmo recomendável face às alternativas, dizer "um terço das mulheres presentes está gravida?"**

Comment: [Off] Acho que não. Parece que sou a única mulher presente e nem estou grávida.

Comment: Lol, fizeste-me engasgar! Nem sequer um terço grávida? Ou grávido? Andamos todos um bocado baralhados.

Comment: Nem sequer um terço. :)

Answer (score 5):

Versão correta:

> Um terço das mulheres estão grávidas.

Porquê? Vejamos:

#### 1: a concordância do verbo não pode ser com o quantificador

(Quantificador?...)

Um terço das mulheres está grávido? Os terços não engravidam...

#### 2: O adjetivo só pode fazer concordância com um substantivo

(Ou com um pronome, que substitui o substantivo.)

Por definição, um adjetivo [`junta-se ao substantivo para o qualificar`](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/adjetivo).
Logicamente, faz concordância com ele.

Não faz concordância com verbos, nem nenhuma outra coisa.

Eis um exemplo com 3 adjetivos a fazer concordância cada um com o seu substantivo - sujeito, objeto direto, objeto indireto:

> O macaco maroto atirou três poios pesados aos indivíduos incrédulos.

#### 3: Alternativamente, percebamos por analogia

Manipulemos a frase à procura de alternativas dela, que nos permitam tirar conclusões sobre como fazer a concordância:

- 1 mulher está grávida - parece-me um exemplo que não levanta dúvidas;
- 1 homem está grávido - exemplo simples;
- 2 mulheres estão grávidas - a concordância mantém-se igual;
- todas as mulheres estão grávidas;
- 100% das mulheres estão grávidas;
- 33% das mulheres estão grávidas;
- Um terço das mulheres estão grávidas.

Chego à conclusão que a concordância é feita com o sujeito.
Bom, com as sujeitas; que os homens não engravidam.

Comment: A tua resposta é uma apologia da concordância siléptica: um terço das mulheres são na realidade várias mulheres, logo... Mas o sujeito gramatical da frase não é "as mulheres", é "um terço das mulheres," masculino singular, e a concordância gramatical, geralmente a preferida pelos gramáticos, leva a  "(...) está grávido." Vê link na  pergunta.

Comment: Percebi, no geral, e fiquei um pouco confuso. Agora é demasiado de manhã, vou reler mais tarde.

Comment: As concordâncias são tramadas. Eu já tinha dado de barato que _está grávido_ e _estão grávidas_ estão ambos corretos (eu também prefiro o último), a minha questão é se _está gravida_, que mistura as duas concordâncias no _grávida_  também está.

Comment: Não li a pergunta com atenção; não percebi que essa era a pergunta - a minha resposta não responde, então! (Só indireta e acidentalmente.)

Comment: Responde. Eu entendi a tua resposta como rejeitando _está grávida_. É uma posição que tem mérito. Já dei +1 e tudo. Mas se andaste a investigar mais o assunto, e quiseres reconsiderar, complementar, qualificar. etceterar, estás à vontade.

Comment: Juntei mais infomação, um artigo do ciberdúvidas, à pergunta. Talvez queiras incorporar. Dá-te alguma razão.

Comment: Eu mandei-lhes a [minha pergunta](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-concordancia-verbal-em-das-mulheres-presentes-um-terco/33589).Vê só como eles conseguiram não lhe responder!

Answer (score 3):

Diria que **sim**. A frase não me soa muito mal (mas soa pior do que "estão grávidas").

Gramaticalmente, o assunto não parece pacífico. Esta resposta do [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/concordancia-total-e-parcial-ou-atractiva/13955) refere-se a este fenómeno como havendo *concordância parcial* (ou *atrativa*) para um aspeto e *concordância global* para outro:

> Note-se que alguns autores admitem que a concordância atractiva possa ocorrer apenas quanto ao género ou quanto ao número, podendo acontecer na mesma frase concordância parcial quanto a um aspecto, e global quanto a outro.
>
> [...]
>
> Se, todavia, quiser optar por uma concordância global em número e atractiva ou parcial em género, saiba que tem autores, como por exemplo Napoleão Mendes de Almeida na sua Gramática Metódica da Língua Portuguesa, p. 457, que referem essa possibilidade.

Este tipo de concordância atrativa parece menos favorecido se usarmos um adjetivo que não é tão tipicamente usado no feminino:

> Um terço das mulheres está satisfeita.

Menos se não se tratar de pessoas:

> Um terço das cadeiras está partida.

E ainda pior se trocarmos os géneros na expressão partitiva:

> Metade dos homens está satisfeito.

Comment: Concordância _global_ é o mesmo que _gramatical_ (com o sujeito gramatical)? Esse deve ser o artigo que discute um sujeito que é uma lista de nomes, creio?

Comment: @Jacinto Certo. Eu pus o link para o artigo, mas tu aparentemente já os conheces todos :p

Comment: Eu referencio este artigo na resposta à tua pergunta (Plebe e Leonor). Uma lista de nomes é diferente de expressão partitiva + substantivo plural. Ainda assim, eu inclino-me a transpor o que eles dizem num caso para o outro. Contudo se dissermos _das mulheres presentes, um terço_... a concordância atrativa dá o mesmo que a global (ou gramatical). A siléptica (em género e número) é que continua a dar _grávidas_. Mas imagino que o que eles dizem para a global e atrativa possa ser válido para a global e siléptica.

Comment: Descobri mais um artigo relevante no ciberdúvidas, que inclui na pergunta. Talvez queiras ver.

Comment: Eu mandei-lhes a [minha pergunta](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-concordancia-verbal-em-das-mulheres-presentes-um-terco/33589).Vê só como eles conseguiram não lhe responder!