# "noventa por cento é... ou noventa por cento são...?"

Tags: concordância-verbal

Ouvi em uma estação de rádio "noventa por cento do povo acham que a situação do país..." e percebi que, nesse caso, eu faria a concordância verbal no singular "noventa por cento do povo acha...".  No entanto, no caso de "noventa por cento dos brasileiros..." eu já fico em dúvida.  Como fazer a concordância nos seguintes casos:

> - noventa por cento do povo / da população / do planeta
> - noventa por cento dos alunos / dos brasileiros / das nossas fronteiras

Certamente deve haver uma regra.

Comment: Mais ou menos relacionado: [Um terço das mulheres presentes pode estar grávida?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/um-ter%c3%a7o-das-mulheres-presentes-pode-estar-gr%c3%a1vida)

Comment: @ANeves e Centaurus, Eu diria que o 90% dos brasileiros é como [*a maior parte de nós concorda/concordam/concordamos*](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/a-maior-parte-e-concord%C3%A2ncia-verbal); *90% do povo* também me parece melhor com singular.

Comment: Também é uma dúvida que tenho frequentemente, mas segundo a pergunta indicada por ANeves deveria ser *noventa por cento são...* uma vez que a segundo diz a resposta a concordância deve ser com o sujeito e não com o quantificador.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos   Mas eu acho que depende de o sujeito ser contável ou não.  Por exemplo:  "noventa por cento do planeta sofre/sofrem com a degradação ambiental."     "Noventa por cento do planeta desconhece/desconhecem noções básicas de higiene."  Povo é incontável.  Brasileiros é contável.  O planeta é incontável, mas se considerarmos o planeta como "toda a população da terra"  torna-se contável?   Podemos considerar 90% como um bloco único ?   Tenho essas dúvidas.

Comment: Penso que continua a aplicar-se sempre a regra de concordância com o sujeito, até porque 'soa melhor', por exemplo 'noventa por cento **do planeta** > sofre', 'Noventa por cento **do planeta** > desconhece', 'Noventa por cento da **população** > desconhece'. Mas se for 'Noventa por cento **dos brasileiros** > desconhecem', independentemente de o sujeito incontável representar ou não sujeitos contáveis.

Comment: Relacionado, mas em inglés: [Technicalities about “%”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/113205).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para porcentagens, o verbo concorda com o termo mais próximo nos casos em que há mais de um. Portanto, na construção:

> noventa por cento do povo acha

o verbo "achar" concorda com "do povo", sendo, portanto, "acha".

Note que se "do povo" estivesse elidido, o verbo passaria a concordar com o número referente à porcentagem.

> Noventa por cento acham (...)
>
> Um porcento acha (...)

Comment: Eu acho que falo assim como tu dizes, mas seria bom citar alguma gramática ou estudo empírico.