# Gospe ou Cospe, qual a forma correta de pronunciar?

Tags: expressões, pronúncia, diferenças

No Português do Brasil temos muitas variacões regionais. Como convivo com pessoas não só do mesmo estado que sou oriundo estas pequenas divergências acontecem.

Uma delas é com a palavra usada para significar expelir saliva pela boca. No Rio Grande do Sul costumamos dizer **gospe**. Em outros estados já ouvi dizer **cospe**.

Qual é a forma correta para o uso desta palavra?

Comment: Imagino então que também se diga *guspidela*, e que aquilo que se guspe seja *o guspo*?

Comment: Exactamente @Jacinto.

Comment: Já morei no RS e em vários estados brasileiros. Nunca vi essa forma escrita. Algumas entonações do sotaque, em especial da região da fronteira, dão a impressão de que trocam o C pelo G em algumas palavras. Influência do espanhol?

Comment: A pronúncia de cuspir e guspir para as crianças é semelhante. Quem não aprendeu a pronúncia correta quando criança fala assim, pois não fez essa associação com palavras derivadas pois eram pequenas demais e sem o conhecimento. Tem quem fale assim. Drible e Dibre é outro exemplo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***Guspir*** vem como variante de *cuspir* nos dicionários Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), Sociedade da Língua Portuguesa (Lisboa, 1962), [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/guspir/), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/guspir) e [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/guspir). Vem sempre classificada de informal, coloquial ou popular. Eu em Portugal nunca ouvi, e alguns dicionários restringem ao Brasil; mas o Houaiss, Priberam e Michaelis não fazem qualquer restrição.

Os sons [k] de ***c***uspir e [g] de ***g***uspir são muito parecidos. São produzidos com a boca e língua nas mesmas posições; a única diferença é que [a garganta vibra para produzir o [g] e não para produzir o [k]](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade/1072#1072). Aliás houve na evolução do latim para o português muitas palavras em que o som [k] mudou para [g].Temos até casos curiosos como [*lugar*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/lugar) e [*local*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/local) que têm ambos a mesma origem, o latim *locale*, ou [*mácula*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/m%C3%A1cula) e [*mágoa*](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/m%C3%A1goa), ambos do latim *macula*.

Comment: Em Portugal também já ouvi "escupir" só por curiosidade.

Comment: Lol, e era *cuspir*? Ou *esculpir* Ou *escapar*?

Comment: "Eu escupi no João e ele levou a mal"

Comment: Pois, eu também levava. E terá sido por engano, atrapalhação (tipo, uma pessoa escupir e falar ao mesmo tempo pode dar azo a as letras escorregarem no escupo e trocarem de lugar), brincadeira, ou era mesmo assim que a pessoa falava?

Comment: Já ouvi várias pessoas a falar assim. Normalmente gente com menos formação. Tu aqui por Braga ouves cada coisa como "tu comestes tudo" ou "a minha mulher fui ao mercado".

Comment: *Comestes, bebestes e fizestes outras coisa* é [um clássico](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/315/o-que-%C3%A9-concord%C3%A2ncia-verbal/1145#1145)

Comment: @JorgeB., em espanhol é *escupir*; se calhar vem de lá.

Comment: Os casos de "lugar" e "local", e "mágoa" e "mácula" são casos diferentes de "guspir" e "cuspir". Nós primeiros casos é uma herdada e outra emprestada do latim respectivamente, no caso de "cuspir" é uma variante mais tardia.

Comment: @ErgativeMan, de acordo; foi só para ilustrar a facilidade de passar de um som para o outro. Aliás, enquanto *cuspir* e *guspir* são variantes, *mágoa* e *mácula* nem são.

Answer (score 2):

Eu moro no Paraná, na Capital. Mas já morei alguns anos no interior, quando piá e adolescente. Sempre ouvi as duas pronúncias da palavra Cuspir e Guspir. Depende muito do grupo de pessoas que a gente convive para perceber as duas formas de falar. As vezes é legal falar GUSPE, outras vezes fica melhor pronunciar CUSPE. O importante mesmo é compreender o que a outra pessoa quer falar!

Answer (score 1):

Como representante daqueles que falam o ptBR, venho dar minha contribuição.  Embora "gospe" seja reconhecida como uma variante regional, eu nunca ouvi essa forma nas minhas muitas décadas de vida no Brasil.  Já estive no Rio Grande do Sul por diversas vezes mas sempre como turista ou para participar de congressos e, talvez por esse motivo, nunca ouvi algum gaúcho dizer "gospir". Por outro lado, embora muitos executem essa ação quase diariamente, a palavra é usada menos frequentemente. E nada como um gaúcho "da gema" para explicar os regionalismos, que lá são muitos.

Comment: Um downvote ?  Poderia ter deixado o motivo.

Comment: Totalmente incomum em meios mais letrados. Porém, não incomum entre os com pouca instrução, que ainda são muitos no Brasil.

Comment: Nos dicionários formais da língua portuguesa, Houaiss versão monousuário 3.0 e Miniaurélio Eletrônico versão 5.12, não consta a forma  "guspir" e sim "cuspir".
Como já falado, a primeira forma é mais utilizada informalmente por pessoas que acreditam estar certa por sempre terem falado de tal maneira.
Sou de Santa Catarina e aqui muitas pessoas também usam "guspir" assim como conjugam esse suposto verbo com a letra "g".

Answer (score 1):

Pra explicar a minha resposta, tenho que falar da minha origem:  Sou gaúcho e tenho graduação em Engenharia Elétrica/Eletrônica, e especial habilidade pra escrever, e também leio muito.  Fui criado e morei num bairro de periferia de Porto Alegre.   Nunca escutei a palavra "cospe" antes de ter meus 30 anos de idade.  Falo e escrevo "gospe" e considero apenas uma variante da linguagem e plenamente aceitável.
Pra deixar claro, acho inaceitável que a academia prescreva como as palavras vão ser pronunciadas ou escritas, tentando engessar a língua.
A escrita deve apenas "escutar"  e por no papel o que seja mais conveniente.

Answer (score 0):

Gospe é uma versão errada da palavra certa Cospe. Pode até estar num dicionário obscuro mas não significa que esteja correta.

É como outras palavras que já ouvi como "córnicis", para se referir à "cobrança de corner no futebol", "uma lata de cambalacho", para se referir a "uma lata de Carbolac" (o impermeabilizante vendido no Brasil), "tem que trocar o fuzil", em referência a "fusível" e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0):

A forma coloquial "guspir", embora seja bastante usada em algumas regiões do Brasil, não é privilegiada pelo VOLP (Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa).

Portanto, ela é considerada *não culta*.