# Why did traffic become "tráfico" and "tráfego"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, expressões-equivalentes

Traffic in many European languages is directly translated to a similar word (French: *trafic*, Spanish: *tráfico*, Italian: *traffico*, German: *traffic*, Romanian: *trafic*). However in Portuguese this word seems to depend on the context it is used:

- if I'm referring to the passage and flow of vehicles, I should use the word [**tráfego**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tr%C3%A1fego).
- if I'm referring to an illegal traffic (commercial or other *illegal* kind), I should use the word [**tráfico**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tr%C3%A1fico).

This question has been asked by Portuguese people many times (e.g. [ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/trafego--trafico-outra-vez/6823), [duvidas.dicio](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/trafego-ou-trafico/), [origemdapalavra](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/pergunta/pergunta-2556/)), but I found none that explained why in Portuguese this difference came to be...

I wanted to understand particularly when **tráfego** started being used, since the word [traffic was first used for the flow of vehicles in 1825](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=traffic&allowed_in_frame=0)... Was it around the same time?

Comment: [German *traffic*](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Traffic) is an anglicism meaning traffic of computer data only. Vehicle traffic is *Verkehr*.

Comment: This helps to understand the different translations of "traffic" in German: http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=traffic

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Português (English below)

[**Tráfego**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tr%C3%A1fego) and [**tráfico**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tr%C3%A1fico) têm a sua origem na palavra italiana [*traffico*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=traffic&allowed_in_frame=0), a qual originalmente, no século XIV, significava *comércio*. A palavra entrou rapidamente na língua portuguesa como **trafego**, e uns séculos mais tarde novamente como **trafico** (os acentos foram acrescentados no século XX). A tabela abaixo mostra a frequência das duas palavras neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/).

```
Século     XV   XVI  XVII  XVIII  XIX    XX
Tráfego    5     22    9     6     21   351
Tráfico    -     -     -     1     99   432
```

No século XV, *tráfego* significava *comércio*, tal como em *Chancelarias Portuguesas*, Dom Duarte I-II, 1433-35 (a letra *u* representa nalguns casos a atual *v*):

> E que nosa senhoria podia saber que os antijgos edificarem hi sua pouoaçom soomente por viuerem pollo **trafego** das mercadorias e as ajuntarem em ella por quanto de lixboa ataa galiza nom acharom outro porto de mar mais seguro que esse.

Nos princípios do século XVII *tráfego* tinha adquirido o significado de *trabalho , negócios, interação social, azáfana, movimento de pessoas*:

> Lisboa é terra grande e a muita confusão da gente e **tráfego** dela a faz embaraçada. ([Francisco Rodrigues Lobo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Rodrigues_Lobo), *Corte na Aldeia e Noites de Inverno*, 1607.)
>
> [E] assim não havia quem se ouvisse em caza com o **trafego** e revolta, porque continuamente de noite e de dia não cessavão, huns a jugar, outros a comer e beber, outros a comprar e vender, outros a enfardelar. ([Luiz Frois (1560-80)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu%C3%ADs_Fr%C3%B3is) *Historia do Japam 2*.)
>
> [É] tão continuada sua romagem de todos os Gentios do Oriente, (…) vendo aquele **tráfego** de romeiros, franqueou aquela romagem a todos liberalmente. ([Diogo do Couto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogo_de_Couto), *Quinta década (livros 8-10), vol. 1, Décadas*, 1584.)

Estes significados de *tráfego* ainda aparecem no dicionários (ver [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/tr%C3%A1fego) ou [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/tr%C3%A1fego)), e ainda eram usados nos finais do século XIX:

> O comércio de importação e exportação de gêneros, mesmo em larga escala, o próprio **tráfego** de africanos, lhe pareciam especulações degradantes e impróprias de sua alta posição e esmerada educação. ([Bernardo Guimarães](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernardo_Guimar%C3%A3es), [*A Escrava Isaura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Escrava_Isaura_(novel)), 1875.)
>
> Ele amava doidamente a padeirinha. Há dias que a tinha visto pela primeira vez, quando ela, como agora, regressava do seu **trafego** habitual. ([Abel Botelho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_Botelho), [*Mulheres da Beira*](http://www.infopedia.pt/$mulheres-da-beira), 1898.)

*Tráfego* com o significado de fluxo de mercadorias ou veículos aparece no Corpus apenas nos finais do século XIX. No século XX esse é praticamente o seu único significado (vi apenas uma amostra das 351 ocorrências no Corpus).

> E de quantos cachorros precisa o senhor para o **tráfego** dos trens diários do Cosme Velho ao Corcovado? ([França Júnior](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7a_J%C3%BAnior), *Caiu o Ministério*, 1883.)
>
> Entretanto, a remoção parcial dos paus, que em trechos salteados atravancam o rio, seria facílima, facultando desde logo, em qualquer tempo, um **tráfego** de viagens seguidas, mesmo para as lanchas de três pés de calado. ([Euclydes da Cunha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclides_da_Cunha), *Canudos e Outros Temas*, 1897?)

Na sua primeira ocorrência no Corpus, 1756, **tráfico** significa *comércio*. No século XIX todas as ocorrências exceto duas tem que ver com o tráfico de escravos, e têm conotação negativa. Cerca de dois terços de todas as entradas vêm da obra do abolicionista brasileiro [José do Patrocínio (1854-1905)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_do_Patroc%C3%ADnio). No século XX *tráfico* é usado sobretudo no contexto de tráfico de droga.

A palavra italiana *traffico* deve ter sido importada oralmente. Não vejo como é que o **c** teria passado a **g** se a palavra tivesse sido importado por escrito. Lisboa era no final da Idade Média um porto internacional importante, e muitos mercadores italianos estabeleceram-se lá. Portanto teriam havido muitas oportunidades para os portugueses se familiarizarem com a palavra. Imagino que marinheiros e comerciantes mudassem o som, e que os escritores da altura simplesmente escrevessem a palavra tal como a ouviam. [Os sons /k/ and /g/ são muito parecidos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/gospe-ou-cospe-qual-a-forma-correta-de-pronunciar). *Tráfico* aparece com conotação negativa praticamente desde o início. Portanto deve ter sido cunhada de novo, possivelmente sob influência francesa. A palavra italiana *traffico* entrou para o francês como *trafic*, e adquiriu muito cedo a conotação de [comércio imoral e clandestino](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commerce_des_esclaves) que*tráfego* nunca teve.

### English

[**Tráfego**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tr%C3%A1fego) and [**tráfico**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tr%C3%A1fico) both ultimately have their origins in the Italian word [*traffico*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=traffic&allowed_in_frame=0), which in its fourteenth century origin meant *trade*. The word was quick to enter the Portuguese language as **trafego**, and centuries later as **trafico** (accents were added in the twentieth century). The table below shows the occurrences of the two words in this [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/).

```
Century  15th  16th  17th  18th  19th  20th
Tráfego    5    22     9     6    21    351
Tráfico    -     -     -     1    99    432
```

In the 15th century, *tráfego* meant trade, as in *Chancelarias Portuguesas*, Dom Duarte I-II, 1433-35 (some *u* are *v* today):

> E que nosa senhoria podia saber que os antijgos edificarem hi sua pouoaçom soomente por viuerem pollo **trafego** das mercadorias e as ajuntarem em ella por quanto de lixboa ataa galiza nom acharom outro porto de mar mais seguro que esse.

By the beginning of the 17th century *tráfego* had also come to mean work, affairs, social interaction, great activity, movement of people:

> Lisboa é terra grande e a muita confusão da gente e **tráfego** dela a faz embaraçada. ([Francisco Rodrigues Lobo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Rodrigues_Lobo), *Corte na Aldeia e Noites de Inverno*, 1607.)
>
> [E] assim não havia quem se ouvisse em caza com o **trafego** e revolta, porque continuamente de noite e de dia não cessavão, huns a jugar, outros a comer e beber, outros a comprar e vender, outros a enfardelar. ([Luiz Frois (1560-80)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu%C3%ADs_Fr%C3%B3is) *Historia do Japam 2*.)
>
> [É] tão continuada sua romagem de todos os Gentios do Oriente, (…) vendo aquele **tráfego** de romeiros, franqueou aquela romagem a todos liberalmente. ([Diogo do Couto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogo_de_Couto), *Quinta década (livros 8-10), vol. 1, Décadas*, 1584.)

These meanings of *tráfego* appear still in the dictionaries (see [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/tr%C3%A1fego) and [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/tr%C3%A1fego)), and were still current in the 19th century:

> O comércio de importação e exportação de gêneros, mesmo em larga escala, o próprio **tráfego** de africanos, lhe pareciam especulações degradantes e impróprias de sua alta posição e esmerada educação. ([Bernardo Guimarães](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernardo_Guimar%C3%A3es), [*A Escrava Isaura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Escrava_Isaura_(novel)), 1875.)
>
> Ele amava doidamente a padeirinha. Há dias que a tinha visto pela primeira vez, quando ela, como agora, regressava do seu **trafego** habitual. ([Abel Botelho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_Botelho), [*Mulheres da Beira*](http://www.infopedia.pt/$mulheres-da-beira), 1898.)

*Tráfego* meaning flow of goods and vehicles appears in the corpus only late in the 19th century. In the 20th century that is basically its only meaning (I’ve merely sampled its 351 occurrences).

> E de quantos cachorros precisa o senhor para o **tráfego** dos trens diários do Cosme Velho ao Corcovado? ([França Júnior](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7a_J%C3%BAnior), *Caiu o Ministério*, 1883.)
>
> Entretanto, a remoção parcial dos paus, que em trechos salteados atravancam o rio, seria facílima, facultando desde logo, em qualquer tempo, um **tráfego** de viagens seguidas, mesmo para as lanchas de três pés de calado. ([Euclydes da Cunha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclides_da_Cunha), *Canudos e Outros Temas*, 1897?)

In its first 1756 appearance **tráfico** means trade. In the nineteenth century all but two occurrences relate to the slave trade and carry a negative connotation.  About two thirds of all entries come from the work of [José do Patrocínio (1854-1905)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_do_Patroc%C3%ADnio), a Brazilian abolitionist. In the twentieth century *tráfico* is used mostly for drug traffic.

The Italian *traffico* must have been imported orally. I cannot see how the **c** would have changed into **g** if it had been imported in writing. Lisbon was a busy international port in the late medieval period, and many Italian merchants actually settled there. So there would been plenty of opportunity for the Portuguese to get acquainted with the word. So I guess sailors and tradespeople changed the sound of it, and writers of the time simply wrote it as they heard it. [The sounds /k/ and /g/ are of course very similar](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/gospe-ou-cospe-qual-a-forma-correta-de-pronunciar). *Tráfico* appears with a negative meaning basically from the start. So it may have been coined anew, possibly under French influence. The Italian *traffico* passed into French as *trafic*, and acquired early on a sense of [immoral and clandestine trade](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commerce_des_esclaves) that *tráfego* never did.

Comment: Indeed, it's not uncommon for a word to be imported twice, the earlier import will more likely have undergone phonetic changes and semantic shifts this creating two different words with different meanings or connotations. Cf. *lugar* / *local*

Comment: Uau, meus votos de milhares de votos positivos para esta resposta. `This question has been asked [...] many times` e *finalmente* tem uma resposta canônica aqui no [portuguese.se] :)