# Tráfigo e tráfego têm o mesmo significado?

Tags: expressões-equivalentes

Tive esta dúvida após ver uma pergunta em um outro site da rede SE, e me indicaram [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/why-did-traffic-become-tr%C3%A1fico-and-tr%C3%A1fego) do pt.se, porém a resposta está em inglês, então creio que seja válido perguntar: Tráfico e tráfego têm o mesmo significado? Podem se substituir livremente em qualquer frase?

Comment: Qualquer coisa fora do aceito pelo site, por favor me avisem, nunca postei aqui antes.

Comment: Nestes casos convém consultar [tráfego](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=tr%E1fego) e [tráfico num dicionário](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=tr%E1fico) e só então, se necessário, fazer a pergunta, indicando quais são as dúvidas que subsistem. A resposta à outra pergunta possivelmente esclarece as tuas dúvidas. Ela trata da evolução dos significados das duas palavras ao longo do tempo. Vou traduzi-la (eu sou o autor).

Comment: @Jacinto obrigado pela tradução, devo deletar a pergunta ou marcá-la como duplicata?

Comment: Eu apagaria, mas o dono da pergunta és tu.

Comment: Grande parte da resposta eram citações já em português, nem deu assim tanto trabalho

Comment: Vou deixar como duplicata para servir de referencia a algum desavisado(como ocorreu comigo).