# "Nós é quem agradecemos" ou "Nós é que agradecemos"?

Tags: gramática

Qual é o correto ou, se ambos estão corretos, qual soa mais correto: "nós é **quem** agradecemos" ou "nós é **que** agradecemos"?

Comment: O mais correto parece-me "nós é que agradecemos", sou de Portugal.

Comment: Nós é quem agradece.

Comment: @AndréLyra *Nós **somos** quem agradece*. Mas *nós é que agradecemos* é correto e mais natural se o objetivo for realçar que somos nós e não outros quem deve agradecer.

Comment: 'Nós é quem agradecemos' é incorreto pois 'quem' pede o verbo no singular independentemente da pessoa a quem 'quem' se refere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A questão aqui não é concordância verbal (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/59/qual-a-forma-correta-fui-eu-quem-fiz-foi-eu-que-fiz-foi-eu-quem-fez-fu) sobre concordância verbal em frases vagamente parecidas), mas sim legitimação pelo uso; e embora haja quem use *nós é quem agradecemos*, a formulação clássica, a que se encontra na literatura e dicionários, é:

> Nós ***é que*** agradecemos.

Esta frase é composta de uma só oração, com sujeito *nós* e verbo *agradecemos* (a frase básica é *nós agradecemos*); ***é que*** é uma locução inserida na frase para realçar que somos nós e não outros quem agradece. A locução [***é que*** vem explicada no Aulete:](http://www.aulete.com.br/que)

> **É que**
>   **1** Us[ado] para dar ênfase, junto a uma parte da frase (um nome, uma expressão, etc.) para a qual se quer chamar a atenção (p.ex., para contrastar ou distinguir algo ou alguém em relação a outros).: *Ela ajudou muito; ele **é que** atrapalhou*.: *Isso **é que** não está certo!*

A locução ***é quem*** não aparece no dicionário [(ver ***quem*** no Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/quem) e é rara na literatura: 58 *nós é que agradecemos* contra 1 *nós é quem agradecemos* no Google Books. Fui ver neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), onde dá para pesquisar de uma só vez *nós é que/quem* seguido de qualquer verbo, e encontrei os seguintes números entre autores dos séculos XIX e XX e imprensa dos anos noventa:

```
                             Eu   Tu    Ele/ela   Você   nós    eles/elas
é que [qualquer verbo]      192   57      116      25     36       42
é quem [qualquer verbo]       1    0       18*      6*     0        1
    * Construção diferente
```

Os raros exemplos de «eu é quem» e «eles é quem» são de entrevistas na imprensa. «Ele/ela/você é quem», que já encontramos em maior abundância, são uma construção diferente. Aqui não temos uma locução *é quem* inserida numa só oração. Temos antes duas orações: [*ele é*] + [*quem + verbo*]. É análoga a *eu sou quem agradece* ou *nós somos quem agradece*, onde *ele* concorda com *é*, *eu* com *sou* e *nós* com *somos*.

Answer (score 5):

A correta é a segunda:

> (1) Nós **é que** agradecemos.

Esta construção chama-se **pseudoclivada invertida de *é que*** (*Gramática do Português*, Maria Mateus e outras, 6.ª ed., Caminho, 2003, pág. 690). A expressão *é que* é reinterpretada como fixa; não admite interrupção ou marcas de tempo e concordância do verbo *ser* (*idem*, pág. 691).

A primeira tem problemas de concordância. A cópula *ser* tem de concordar com *nós* e *agradecer* tem de concordar com *quem* (que leva geralmente o verbo para a 3.ª do singular, embora se admitam por vezes exceções):

> (2) Nós **somos** quem **agradece**.

Neste caso temos um predicado identificacional, onde o verbo *ser* estabelece uma relação de identidade entre os dois argumentos (*nós* e *quem agradece*). Parece-me difícil ler esta frase como uma clivada, onde o foco é *nós* e não a oração *quem agradece* (sobre esta ambiguidade, ver [esta dissertação de Mariana Resenes](https://repositorio.ufsc.br/bitstream/handle/123456789/92538/261462.pdf?sequence=1), pág. 54). Por outro lado, a leitura de clivada é facilmente apercebida nestas outras frases:

> (3) **Somos nós quem** agradece.
>   (4) **Somos nós que** agradecemos.

*Que* não pode ser usado na frase (2) em lugar de *quem*; para usar *que* seria preciso que o pronome relativo tivesse um antecedente explícito:

> (5) Nós somos **as pessoas *que*** agradecem.

As frases (1) e (3-4) (mas não (2)) têm um foco contrastivo (põem em foco *nós* em oposição a outra pessoa ou grupo de pessoas):

> — Agradeço muito o trabalho.
>   — Nós **é que** agradecemos (que use os nossos serviços).

ou

> — O João vai ser o primeiro a agradecer.
>   — Não, nós **é que** agradecemos (primeiro).

ou, agora sem haver duas partes a agradecer:

> Eles acham que nos estão a fazer um favor, e a culpa é nossa — nós **é que** agradecemos sempre.

Já a outra frase parece-me difícil usá-la com *agradecer* no presente sem que haja mais qualquer coisa. Por exemplo, à pergunta *Quem agradece primeiro?*, poderia responder-se *Nós somos quem agradece primeiro*.