# Com a expressão "um dos que" o verbo fica sempre no plural? Por quê?

Tags: expressões, concordância-verbal, concordância-nominal

Pelo que pesquisei em alguns sites, trata-se de uma questão um pouco polêmica. Por isso, compartilho aqui com vocês.

> **Exemplo 1** - flexão correta do verbo:
>   Ronaldo foi um dos jogadores que mais *brilharam* na Seleção Brasileira.
>
> **Exemplo 2** - flexão incorreta do verbo:
>   Ronaldo foi um dos jogadores que mais *brilhou* na Seleção Brasileira.

A concordância verbal nos leva a pensar que o **Exemplo 2** é que está correto.

Com a expressão "um dos que" o verbo fica sempre no plural? Por quê?

Comment: "A concordância verbal nos leva a pensar que o Exemplo 2 é que está correto."  Você quis mesmo dizer "Exemplo 2"?   A concordância verbal me leva a pensar que o exemplo 1 é que está correto:  "brilharam" refere-se a jogadores, e não a Ronaldo.

Comment: Simplesmente porque mais de um jogador brilhou, então tem de ficar no plural

Comment: @Centaurus, você tem razão, inicialmente pensei que "brilhou" estava se referindo a Ronaldo que é o sujeito.

Comment: Se quiser singular teria de mudar para numa construção alternativa pouco usual e desconexa "Ronaldo foi um dos jogadores quem mais brilhou na seleção brasileira"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na verdade muitos gramáticos aceitam as duas construções, e ambas foram usadas pelos nossos melhores escritores. A flexão plural tem no entanto uma lógica imbatível, como creio que salta à vista com esta brincadeirazinha:

> (a1) : Ronaldo foi um dos jogadores.
>   (b): Quais jogadores?
>   (a2): **Os jogadores** que mais **brilharam** na Seleção Brasileira.

Em (a2) tem que ser *brilharam*; jamais poderia ser *brilhou*. A justificação para a flexão plural na frase única é a mesma:

> Ronaldo foi um dos jogadores **que mais brilharam**

O trecho em negrito, **que mais brilharam**, é uma oração relativa restritiva que adjetiva *jogadores*: identifica os jogadores de que estamos a falar. Quando o sujeito é o pronome relativo *que*, o verbo concorda com o antecedente do pronome, neste caso *jogadores*, como discutido [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/59/qual-a-forma-correta-fui-eu-quem-fiz-foi-eu-que-fiz-foi-eu-quem-fez-fu). Estamos a dizer que vários jogadores **brilharam**, e que Ronaldo foi um deles. Vejamos outro exemplo,

> (c) [Uma das pessoas **que presenciaram a cena**] contou-nos o ocorrido.

Novamente, na oração relativa restritiva em negrito, o verbo, *presenciam*, concorda com *pessoas*, que é o antecedente do pronome relativo *que*. Por sua vez, a expressão entre colchetes — *uma das pessoas que presenciaram a cena* — é o sujeito do verbo *contar*; esse sujeito é singular — *uma*… — logo o verbo *contar* vem no singular.

A flexão plural é defendida deste modo por João Andrade Peres e Telmo Móia em *Áreas Críticas da Língua Portuguesa* (Lisboa, Caminho, 1995, pp. 495/496), citado [neste artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-concordancia-na-sequencia-uma-das-razoes-pelas-quais/29576). Eles consideram a flexão singular nestes casos «anormal no plano sintático e ilógica no plano semântico». A razão que eles adiantam, exemplificando nós com o nosso exemplo, é que nós temos um sintagma nominal — *jogadores que brilharam/brilhou* — e o verbo no singular da frase relativa concorda não «com o pronome relativo — ou o seu antecedente —, mas, sim, com o quantificador *um*, que é um elemento exterior ao sintagma nominal que primariamente contém a construção relativa».

No entanto, os próprios João Peres e Temo Móia reconhecem que a flexão singular é aceite por falantes, escritores e algumas gramáticas. O [artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-concordancia-na-sequencia-uma-das-razoes-pelas-quais/29576) e este [artigo no Gramaticalhas](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI11372,101048-Um+dos+que) apresentam as posições de alguns gramáticos que aceitam a flexão singular.

Não encontrei no entanto nenhum argumento que rebatesse o raciocínio de João Peres e Telmo Móia em favor da flexão plural. O que vários gramáticos dizem é que a flexão singular destaca o indivíduo, e a plural dá mais destaque ao grupo a que o indivíduo pertence. Parece-me no entanto que há casos em que é possível argumentar que, em ***um dos [substantivo plural] que***, o pronome relativo ***que*** se refere ao ***um*** e não ao substantivo plural. Isto é claro nesta passagem de [José de Alencar em *O Guarani*, 1857:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_gS6DAAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&lpg=PT30&dq=%22um%20dos%20aventureiros%20que%20tocava%22&source=bl&ots=5InvLmA3dc&sig=73U0jPiT78afGLnPWxMt5FKCHW4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxibOl4c3OAhWLuBQKHSquCw0Q6AEINjAE#v=onepage&q=%22um%20dos%20aventureiros%20que%20tocava%22&f=false)

> (d) De repente, os sons melancólicos de um clarim prolongaram-se pelo ar quebrando o concerto da tarde; era **um dos aventureiros que tocava** a Ave-Maria.

Aqui não se diz que vários aventureiros tocavam um único clarim; há um indivíduo que toca o clarim, e esse indivíduo é um dos aventureiros. Portanto aqui o antecedente do *que* é *um dos aventureiros*, e não simplesmente *os aventureiros*. Creio que seja possível argumentar do mesmo modo em relação a [esta outra passagem do Guarani](https://books.google.pt/books?id=UttkDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT231&lpg=PT231&dq=%22um%20dos%20aventureiros%20que%20estava%22&source=bl&ots=8r9HiQ0-cu&sig=BgnZMnx1mY6hcoeVBra2-N7ArpQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-kPaazM3OAhXB8RQKHTR2B2QQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22um%20dos%20aventureiros%20que%20estava%22&f=false):

> (e) Os aventureiros comandados por Loredano arregimentaram-se e marcharam para a casa […] Quase ao mesmo tempo **um dos aventureiros que estava** ao lado de Loredano caiu traspassado por uma flecha.

Se entendermos que o antecedente de *que* é *um dos aventureiros* o verbo *estar* deve vir naturalmente no singular. É como se disséssemos,

> (f) Quase ao mesmo tempo, dos aventureiros, **um que estava** ao lado de Loredano caiu traspassado por uma flecha;

e não,

> (g) Quase ao mesmo tempo, dos **aventureiros que estavam** ao lado de Loredano, um caiu traspassado por uma flecha.

Para (f) ser um interpretação legítima de (e) é necessário que seja claro de que aventureiros estamos a falar, não sendo por isso necessária uma frase relativa para definir quem eles são, ao contrário do que se passa na interpretação (g).

Mas se algumas flexões singulares podem ser explicadas deste modo, como eu penso que podem, encontram-se muitas que não podem, como por exemplo em [José de Alencar, *O Sertanejo*, 1875](https://books.google.pt/books?id=vchcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT381&lpg=PT381&dq=Foi%20o%20Xavier%20um%20dos%20que%20mordeu%20o%20p%C3%B3&source=bl&ots=xL4AjZA1cQ&sig=BhyNLqzyp5oc5ahQmiO4hExMfQE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM-5fyss3OAhVTnRQKHehjCxwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Foi%20o%20Xavier%20um%20dos%20que%20mordeu%20o%20p%C3%B3&f=false)

> Foi o Xavier **um dos que mordeu** o pó.

Esta frase é claramente equivalente a *foi o Xavier um dos indivíduos que morderam o pó*: a oração relativa *que mordeu o pó* define quem são os ***os*** de que Xavier faz parte. Portanto a lógica gramatical exigiria *os que morderam*, mas o autor preferiu *os que mordeu*. Isto parece-me verdade sempre que tenhamos simplesmente *um dos que* (precisamos de uma oração relativa para difinir quem são os **os**) em vez de *um dos [substantivo plural] que*. Talvez por isso Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (*Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, Lisboa, 2014, p. 625-6) façam um distinção entre os dois casos. No entanto fazem-no apenas quanto ao uso, sem análise gramatical: no caso de *um dos [substantivo plural] que*, dizem que o verbo «vai para a 3.ª pessoa do plural ou, mais raramente, para a 3ª pessoa do singular»; no caso de *um dos que* dizem que são raros os exemplos literários com o verbo no singular.

Mas mesmo no caso de *um dos [substantivo plural] que*, encontram-se na literatura imensos casos de verbos flexionados no singular para os quais não consigo encontrar justificação gramatical. Parece-me que essas construções são aceites por nos soarem bem e terem sido frequentemente usada por escritores de nomeada. Eis dois exemplos entre os muitos que se encontram por aí:

> E a **um dos primeiros que quis** ir fazer esta obra, que era João Freire, page de Tristão da Cunha, ao saltar de um eirado em outro, foi morto per eles. [[João de Barros (1496-1570)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo%C3%A3o_de_Barros#Obras), [*A Ásia: Segunda Década*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ndA5AQAAIAAJ&q=%22um%20dos%20primeiros%20que%20quis%22&dq=%22um%20dos%20primeiros%20que%20quis%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic8pn6uM3OAhVEPxQKHfR_ADsQ6AEIHTAA).]

O que se diz aqui não é, *dos primeiros, um que quis ir* (quais primeiros?); é *dos primeiros que quiseram ir, um*.

> E Carlos, furando, pôde enfim avistar no meio do montão **um dos sujeitos que correra** no premio dos Productos [[Eça de Queiroz, *Os Maias*, 1888.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ODa-CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT1278&dq=%22um%20dos%20sujeitos%20que%20correra%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE9MPkwM3OAhXEzxQKHYYQCNkQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%22um%20dos%20sujeitos%20que%20correra%22&f=false)

Também aqui não é, *entre os sujeitos, avistou um que correra* (quais sujeitos); é *entre os sujeitos que correram, avistou um*.

Note-se por fim, que tudo isto só se aplica quando o pronome relativo *que* é sujeito da oração relativa. Por exemplo em, *este é um dos livros que (eu) comprei*, o *que* é objeto direto, e naturalmente o verbo concorda com *eu*, não como *livros*.