# Oração subordinada adjetiva após locução adjetiva

Tags: orações-subordinadas

Como interpretar as duas frases seguintes, por favor?

"Ele é o diretor daquela escola, que detesto."

"Ele é o diretor daquela escola que detesto."

Elas têm o mesmo significado? Uma delas está correta e a outra não? Qual expressa que não se gosta do "diretor daquela escola" e qual expressa que não se gosta "daquela escola na qual a pessoa é a diretora"?

Comment: 1) Não; 2) Ambas estão corretas; 3) Se você deseja passar a informação que detesta o diretor, há uma ambiguidade. A meu ver, o *que* retoma o temo *escola*; logo, com vírgula, eu interpreto que eu sei que no contexto há *uma* escola, sem vírgula, eu passo a imaginar que há *outras* escolas. (Não sei se deu para entender ou se ficou confuso :S)

Comment: Há duas possibilidades: Ele é o **diretor que detesto** daquela escola. Ele é o diretor **daquela escola que detesto**.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please don't forget to [accept it by clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Esta frase é formada por duas orações:

1. *Ele é o diretor daquela escola.*
2. *que detesto.*

Na segunda oração, o **"que" é** um **pronome relativo** que retoma o termo antecedente "escola", e não diretor. "Detesto aquela escola". Caracterizando uma **Oração Subordinada Adjetiva (OSA)**.

As orações subordinadas adjetivas **podem ser explicativas ou restritivas**. Nas explicativas a pontuação é obrigatória e nas restritivas a pontuação é proibida.

- **Primeiro caso**:

*"Ele é o diretor daquela escola, que detesto."*

É uma **OSA explicativa**. Significa que você está falando de um diretor de uma escola e explica que detesta escolas.

Seria como: *"Acabei tomando o suco de manga, que detesto"*. (Detesto qualquer suco de manga)

- **Segundo caso**:

*"Ele é o diretor daquela escola que detesto."*

É uma **OSA restritiva**. Significa que existem escolas que você detesta, outras que não detesta, e que está se restringindo ao diretor de uma escola que você detesta.

Seria como: *"Acabei tomando o suco de manga que detesto"*. (Detesto alguns sucos de manga e tomei um deles)

- **Possibilidades**:

Para se referir ao diretor, com a mesma construção, ficaria um pouco estranho.

*"Ele é o diretor que detesto daquela escola."*

Nessa OSA restritiva, existem diretores que você detesta e você está falando de um deles, que é daquela escola.

Ou poderia usar um pronome relativo mais adequado:

*"Ele é o diretor daquela escola o qual detesto."*

Comment: Sim senhor, quanto às vírgulas e explicativa/restritiva. Mas duvido que o relativo *que* tenha **obrigatoriamente** de retomar *escola* e não *diretor daquela escola*. Se assim for, uma frase como [A planta nativa da Europa que é amplamente difundida e utilizada também na culinária brasileira possui... (vê pergunta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/isolando-ora%c3%a7%c3%b5es-com-v%c3%adrgulas-qual-seria-o-sentido-da-senten%c3%a7a-sem-elas) é absurda, porque A Europa não é ingrediente culinário. Creio que é uma questão de pragmática o *que* retomar o mais curto item >>

Comment: >> à esquerda quando a lógica permite retomá-lo a ele ou ou um maior que o inclui (*escola* ou *diretor daquela escola*); é uma maneira de resolver a ambiguidade. [Outra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/com-a-express%c3%a3o-um-dos-que-o-verbo-fica-sempre-no-plural-por-qu%c3%aa) com exemplos em que o relativo *que* retoma o "item longo".

Answer (score 0):

Também entendo que o sentido não seja o mesmo. A separação com vírgula da ênfase no *destestar*, então amplifica o sentido da segunda oração. Agora, entendo que deva ser escrito de outra forma, que evite a ambiguidade, a não ser que seja o sentido desejado. *"Detesto ele, o diretor daquela escola."*, por exemplo.